# Scraping issues on whoscall.in using BeautifulSoup 4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My python script, using BeautifulSoup, can't seem to grasp the words out of the divs on the page, is there a specific reason for this? I can grab the profile pictures to count the number of messages, but, not the text itself.

(For reference, I have used this page: http://whoscall.in/1/2392247496/)

```
if(website == "1"):  
  reqInput = "http://whoscall.in/1/%s/" % (teleWho)
  urlfile = urllib2.Request(reqInput)
  print (reqInput)
  time.sleep(1)
  requestRec = requests.get(reqInput)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(requestRec.content, "lxml")
  noMatch = soup.find(text=re.compile(r"no reports yet on the phone number"))
  print(requestRec.content)# #only if needed#
  type(noMatch) is str
  if noMatch is None:
     worksheet.write(idx+1, 2, "Got a hit")
     howMany = soup.find_all('img',{'src':'/default-avatar.gif'})
     howManyAreThere = len(howMany)
     worksheet.write(idx+1,1,howManyAreThere)
     print (howManyAreThere)
     scamNum = soup.find_all(text=("scam"),recursive=True)
     #,'scam','Scammer','scammer'#
     scamCount = len(scamNum)
     print(scamNum)
     searchTerms = {scamCount:scamCount}
     sentiment = max(searchTerms, key=searchTerms.get)
     worksheet.write(idx+1,3,sentiment)
```

I can't seem to pull the text "scam" off of the page

I'm unsure why it refuses to find that text, as the other Beautiful Soup code works perfectly.

https://github.com/GarnetSunset/Haircuttery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line :

```
scamNum = soup.find_all(text=("scam"),recursive=True)
```

to :

```
scamNum = [ div.text for div in soup.find_all('div', {'style':'font-size:14px; margin:10px; overflow:hidden'}) if 'scam' in div.text.lower() ]
```

Try this for multiple words :

```
words = [ 'word1', 'word2', ... ]
scamNum = [ div.text for div in soup.find_all('div', {'style':'font-size:14px; margin:10px; overflow:hidden'}) if any( word for word in words if word in div.text.lower()) ]
```

Comment: Thanks, glad i could help

Comment: Last thing, thought you'd like this. https://github.com/GarnetSunset/Haircuttery/commit/93a12ab60eea9df36339a1378966f8f9fd0ecc78

Comment: That's too kind

Comment: :)
Last question, feel free to tell me off for this, but, using your code, how would I have to modify it to search for multiple words? ['scam','scammer'] doesn't seem to work, thanks!

Comment: You could use `or` eg : `if 'scam' in div.text.lower() or 'scammer' in div.text.lower() ` , but in this case you dont need to ( 'scam'  is in 'scammer' )

Comment: Thank you so much!